# Why is a table Scan being performed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

```
SELECT X.ID, X.Field4
FROM 
        #TaxInvoiceData T
INNER JOIN
        xxx X
        ON  T.Id = X.Id
        AND Field2 = @VAR     
        AND Field3 = 'S'
```

When I run a query a Full table scan on table X.  I do not understand why because the Primary Key of Table X is

```
ID INT ASC
Field3 CHAR(2) ASC
Field2 DATETIME ASC  Unique Non-clustered
```

There is also an index on

```
Field2 DATETIME ASC  Non-Unique Non-clustered
```

Doing just

```
SELECT ID
FROM xxx
WHERE 
    Field2 = @VAR   
AND Field3 = 'S'
```

Does an Index Seek

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many rows are in #TaxInvoiceData?

Comment: *Does an Index Seek* - ok, but on **which index** ??? Also: you say `(ID, Field2, Field3)` are the primary key on your `Table X` - is that the **clustered index** on the table, too?? Or is this a heap??

Comment: How is S joined to the query? It might be that since the primary key i s not clustered it is faster to scan the table than to jump between the index and the table for every row.

Comment: Joe -- TaxInvoiceData -- 29,053 RECORDS
XXX -- 2,027,206 RECORDS

Comment: Marc S -- it is a non-cluster primary key and it is the PK that is being used in the second query, good question

Comment: idstam-- sorry S should have been X

Comment: @Mike - Have you tried putting `X.` in front of `Field2` and `Field3` in the query?

Comment: Also, how many rows are you expecting to retrieve?  Sometimes optimizers will just cost the table scan as better, if the percentage is high enough (something like 80% or so).

Comment: Mark-- Using Lost IN AL, which also has the alias infront of the fields did not affect the query plan.  X-zero -- 29,053 although I am getting right now 29,051 so that is going to be fund looking into.

Comment: The reason your second query can use the index is because the PK is a covering index for that query. Your first query selects `Field4` which requires hitting the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: because the optimizer thinks it would be faster.

However, let's try to read the optimizer's mind.

Since you haven't provided full table schema, I'm going to assume that there's a clustered index on `xxx.ID` and that `#TaxInvoiceData` is a heap. You're expecting a plan where the PK index is probed for every row in `#TaxInvoiceData`, but you're selecting `xxx.Field4` which is going to require a bookmark lookup for every match. This could result in 29,000 random I/O requests. Ouch.

Conversely, SQL Server could (and apparently is going to) just perform a larger amount of more efficient sequential I/O doing the table scan and is probably doing a speedy hash match against `#TaxInvoiceData`.

So what can you do? You could  create a covering index including `Field4`. Or you could use index and join hints to force the plan you're looking for (but I suspect performance wouldn't be as good as you hope). Is this query used frequently enough that it is giving your application performance problems or are you just looking to eliminate table scans on principle? If the latter, you may find the overhead of getting rid of the scan isn't worth it in the end.

---

Edit:

Since you've mentioned that there's no clustered index on the table, this also may affect how efficient lookups from the index are. Unless this table is seeing extremely heavy insert activity, consider changing your PK to clustered. That alone may change the plan, and even if it doesn't it's likely to speed up other operations due to reduced overhead.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation,which people agree with.  But forgive my ignorance I don't understand why Field4 makes a difference since it is the select and not the where clause I would think it would work like this, find the page/row/leaf by the where clause and grab the field from that row.  So I am not understanding how an index of Field4 would improve a search.  Also there is no clustered index only the PK which was set to Non-clustered for whatever reason.

Comment: If everything the query needs is contained in an index, SQL Server can just look there and avoid using the table entirely. This is called a "covering index" for the query and is usually very efficient. This is not the case for your situation because Field4 has to be read from the table. The problem is due to the fact that repeatedly (many thousands of times) looking up the row in the table referenced by an index row is not very efficient due to I/O overhead. The optimizer is considering all of this when it decides what to do.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe rewriting the query would help:

```
SELECT X.ID, X.Field4 
FROM  xxx X,  #TaxInvoiceData T 
WHERE X.Id = T.Id        
AND X.Field2 = @VAR              
AND X.Field3 = 'S'
```

Comment: Thanks for the time, but that did not change the query plan.

Comment: This is not standard `JOIN` syntax, rewriting the query this way should have no impact *and* make the code worse, -1